# Multiple python commands does not run from bash

Tags: bash, django-celery, django-wsgi

I have a bash script that launches wsgi for python and celery as well. The pythib project launes nicely though celery does not work. Below i incluse two ways of invoking the wsgi project and celery and none works as expected.

Way No1

```
...
echo "the PWD of project now is : ${PWD}"
exec    gunicorn project.wsgi:application \
        --name audit_tool \
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
        --timeout 1000 \
        --workers 4 \
        --log-level=$level \
        --env DEBUG=${DEBUG} \
        --log-config tmp.conf \
        --preload &&
echo "Gunicorn started"
exec celery -A project worker -Q celery --loglevel=info --concurrency=1 --max-memory-per-child=25000 &&
sleep 2.5
ps aux | grep celery ;
echo 'done'
```

```
...
read -r -d '' cmd << end
    gunicorn project.wsgi:application \
        --name audit_tool \
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
        --timeout 1000 \
        --workers 6 \
        --log-level=$level \
        --env DEBUG=${DEBUG} \
        --log-config tmp.conf \
        --preload
end
echo Starting Gunicorn.
($cmd)
read -r -d '' cmd2 << end
    celery \
        -A project \
            worker \
        -Q celery \
        --loglevel=info \
        --concurrency=1 \
        --max-memory-per-child=25000 
end
echo "Starting celery." 
($cmd2)
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

I tried the two above ways and expectation was to launch the wsgi project and celery as well.

Comment: Try removing `exec` everywhere.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @MarkSetchell in the second approach i dont use exec and i have the exact same result

Comment: I was referring to the first example, which does have `exec`. When you say it doesn't work, what happens exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell it executes the gunicorn project.wsgi:application and stops there its does not executes the celery part

Comment: So, add an ampersand at the end to put it in the background.

Comment: `exec` is used to *replace* the script in the current process with another command. It is not needed simply to execute another command.

Comment: @chepner yes in the second approach without the exec we have the same result.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  you mean ($cmd)&  ? like so?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want it to work...

If you want to do `thing1`, wait till it finishes, then `thing2`, use:

```
thing1
thing2
```

If you want to do `thing1` and at the same time `thing2`, use:

```
thing1 &
thing2
```

If `thing1` is actually 2 things, `thing1A` and `thing1B`, then you can combine them (*Do not omit spaces ever. You may omit the semi-colons if the commands are spread across multiple lines*):

```
{ thing1A ; thing1B ; }
```

---

So, in answer to your question:

You can do it like this:

```
{ gunicorn project.wsgi:application \
        --name audit_tool \
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
        --timeout 1000 \
        --workers 4 \
        --log-level=$level \
        --env DEBUG=${DEBUG} \
        --log-config tmp.conf \
        --preload &&
echo "Gunicorn started" } &

{ celery -A project worker -Q celery --loglevel=info --concurrency=1 --max-memory-per-child=25000 &&
sleep 2.5
ps aux | grep celery } &
```

So that starts `gunicorn` and your `echo` command in the background, and while that is still running, it starts `celery`, `sleep` and `ps` as another group of commands running in parallel with `gunicorn`.

Comment: adding those {} made the container failed , removing them it still runs only gunicorn. Very strange behaviour

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`. Do you have a proper shebang at the start? You can change the curly brackets for round ones and try.

Comment: Positively using bash :-) i will try with parentesis

Comment: no luck so far trying all sorts of variations.

Comment: Try simplifying it till it works `gunicorn PARAMETERS &` on one line then `celery PARAMETERS &` on the next, without all the `echo` and `sleep` and `ps`